# XMLQuery in DB2

Tags: jquery, xml, db2, clob, qxmlquery

We have a CLOB column, in a DB2 database that contains XML.  The query does not seem to like the embedded xmlns.  I simplified the query down to this:

`values xmlquery('$rf/Producers/FIRMS/FIRM/EIN/text()' passing xmlparse(document '<Producers xmlns="http://yummy.cupcakes.com"><FIRMS><FIRM><EIN>27</EIN></FIRM>/</FIRMS></Producers>') as "rf")`

If I remove the xmlns embedded in Producers, it works.  As is, it does not return anything, but does not throw an error.  Like I said, this is simplified for troubleshooting.  In reality, the document would be from a CLOB column in our DB.  All th XML stored in the CLOBs contains the xmlns.  Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a default namespace right in the `XMLQUERY`.

```
SELECT XMLQUERY (
  'declare default element namespace "http://yummy.cupcakes.com";
   ...
```

Reference link: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=tutorial-lesson-6-querying-xml-data

Comment: @NotWoz, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark is Answer.